# Fit coords to Google Map V3 LatLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, coords

I'm trying to fit the x & y coords I get from a game to a custom image map with Google Maps V3.

The coords I get from the game are both between 0 and 15360. In the custom map the NorthEast corner `LatLng` is (95, 180) and the SouthWest corner `LatLng` is (-82.5, -180).

So, my function to transform from game coords to Google Map `LatLng` is:

```
function getLatLngFromCoords(x, y) {
    x = parseFloat(x.replace(",", "."));
    y = parseFloat(y.replace(",", "."));
    var lng = x / (15360 / 360) - 180;
    var lat = y / (15360 / 177.5) - 95;
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}
```

but it doesn't fit right to the positions.

I got the NorthEast and SouthWest `LatLng` making Markers and adjusting them to see when they was in the corner of my image map.

Wherever, when I get the bounds of the map with `map.getBounds()`

I see this:

```
    map.getBounds().getNorthEast(); // nb: 89.76247963221984, ob: 180
    map.getBounds().getSouthWest(); // nb: -87.43214656352167, ob: -180
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong latitude value for NorthEast corner. Your values are `LatLng` (95, 180). Maximum value for latitude is 90, so this is most probably cutoff to (90, 180).

For example, using

```
new google.maps.LatLng(95, 180);
```

I got object:

```
Q {nb: 90, ob: 180, toString: function, ...
```